# Java Regex Match

Tags: java, regex

Given such `Regex` code:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("c:.*?(|t:){1}.*?").matcher(string);
```

I only want to match something like `c:somesubstring|t:somesubstring`. However it also matches some thing like this:

```
c:somesubstring
```

and

```
c:somesubstring|a:somesubtring
```

How could this come? I use `(|t:){1}` to guarantee that the pattern `|t:` occurs and occurs only once. Will be helpful to tell me what's wrong with my `regex` and give me a `regex` to match only `c:somesubstring|t:somesubstring`

Comment: `{1}` does *not* guarantee that the preceding item does not appear more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is a special meta character in regex which acts like a logical OR operator usually used to combine two regexes . You need to escape the `|` symbol, so that it would match a literal `|` symbol.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("c:.*?(\\|t:){1}.*?").matcher(string);
```

much shorter.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("c:.*?\\|t:.*?").matcher(string);
```

Comment: or put `|` in a char class like `[|]`